# Fix material stretching in 2.8

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a texture that I apply on a cylinder mesh. The UV map seems ok, but on the sides of the cylinder the texture is stretched.

[image]

I tried to subdivide the vertices, but it didn't worked.
And as you can see the cylinder didn't even got rounder.

[image]
[image]

How can I fix the stretching and why the cylinder didn't got rounder?

Comment: maybe first apply the scale of your object (ctrl A > Scale)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've stretched the sides in the uv map to be taller, but no wider, hence the stretch.

If you subdivide the sides it will just place the new vertex in the middle of the other two, with no interpolation, hence why it doesn't get smoother. Subdivide smooth or the subdiv modifier are much better than doing it yourself.